# get all authorities of a specific user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've got a `User` entity and each user which exists should have 1 or more specific roles/authorities. For example `admin` `user`and so on.
So I created an `authorities` table with 2 fields (`username` and `authority`)
In my `application-context-securtiy.xml` I have

```
<jdbc-user-service id="userService" data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="
        select nickname, password, true from users where nickname=?"
    authorities-by-username-query= "select username, authority AS authorities 
    from authorities where username=?" 
/>
```

which is working quite good.

Right now I'm trying to create a jsp file which lists all of my users and their roles/authorities but I'M not able todo something like `user.getAuthorites()` and print them in the jsp.

I already tried implemented a `UserDetailsService` but I don't know how to connect my User and the UserDetailsService.

Hope you can give me some advice.

Edit:
part of the jsp how I would like to use it:

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="user" varStatus="stats" items="${users}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${user.nickname}" />
            <c:forEach var="role" varStatus="status_" items="${user.getAuthorities()}">
                <c:out value="${role}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>options</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

How I send data from controller to my view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/manageUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String startManageUsers(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
    List<User> list = userService.getUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users", list);    
    return "showUsers";
}
```

Comment: Can you show your JSP code?

Comment: `items="${user.getAuthorities('}"`? Remove missmatched paren and ' in the end. Plus, you probably want `items="${user.authorities}"`

Comment: yeah this was just a typo... I don't know how to implement the stuff that it will work this way in general

Comment: If `user` is a standard User, then `user.authorities` should work IMO.

Comment: How are you putting `users` in the model?

Comment: @Xaerxess when I do `user.authorities` I get `'${user.authorities}' Error reading 'authorities' on type de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.glaeskeLensing.editorials.domain.User`

Comment: Show us your `User` class then. It should have a method getAuthorities if you want this snippet to work.

Comment: I have to implement the following method `@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
           }` but I don't know how to connect this with my services to load the data from the database

Comment: @soupdiver So the problem is that you don't have `getAuthorities()` method in `de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.glaeskeLensing.editorials.domain.User` properly implemented or what?

Comment: yeah because I don't know how to fetch the data at this point

Comment: Do you use some kind of JPA? and please post the class `de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.glaeskeLensing.editorials.domain.User` it is the one that is the key to the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to do this is to implement UserDetailsService and UserDetails.

Example implementation of UserDetailsService.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserLoginService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity userEntity = this.userService.getUserByUserId(userId);
        if (userEntity == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        UserLoginBean bean = new UserLoginBean(userEntity.getId(), userEntity.getUserId(), userEntity.getPassword(), userEntity.getEnabled());
        bean.setFullname(userEntity.getFullname());
        bean.setUserEntity(userEntity);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( userEntity.getRole() ) );
        bean.setAuthorities(roles);

        return bean;
    }

}
```

Example implementation of UserDetails.

```
public class UserLoginBean implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String fullname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean locked;
    private Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;

    private UserEntity userEntity;

    public UserLoginBean(Long id, String username, String password, boolean locked ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities( Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities ) {
        if ( this.authorities == null ) {
            this.authorities = authorities;
        }
    }

    // setters, getters
    }
```

The last thing is to configure spring security to UserLoginService as authentication provider.

Example:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userLoginService">
      <security:password-encoder ref="userPasswordEncoder"/>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean

    <bean id="userLoginService" class="com.stackoverflow.UserLoginService" />
```

In the jsp page you need to add:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="a" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<a:authentication property="principal" var="principal" />
```

Now you can access all the things in UserLoginBean.

```
<c:if test="${not empty principal && principal != 'anonymousUser'}">
        <c:set var="fullname"><c:out value="${principal.fullname}" /></c:set>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: sorry but this is too far in the past and I'm not more into this project so I can't verify your answer :/